# Запятая во фразе "Хищники или борьба с правосудием"

Tags: пунктуация

В названии книги "Хищники или борьба с правосудием" нужно ли ставить запятую?

Answer (score 4):

В двойных названиях запятая ставится, например:

Похождения Чичикова, или Мёртвые души.

Фильм "Плюмбум, или Опасная игра".

(начало второго названия  - с заглавной буквы)

http://www.rosental-book.ru/ortho_iii.html#sect26.2

Answer (score -1):

Если это двойное название, то да, запятая нужна.
Но в вашем случае при желании его можно счесть обычным названием с союзом "или".
Тогда запятая не нужна.

Сравните: "Кошелек или жизнь". Вряд ли в названии такой гипотетической книги кто-то углядит двойное название... Для рассматриваемого примера такое выглядит несколько натянуто, но некоторая возможность остается. 
Если у автора уточнить нет возможности, то, конечно, запятую лучше проставить.